# Missing Run/Debug Configuration: Android Test in Android Studio For ActivityTestRule

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Android Studio Version: 2.3.1

I am looking for the [Run/Debug Configuration: Android Test](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/run-debug-configuration-android-test.html) after I wrote a test in a class having a ClassRule creating an ActivityTestRule instance. But I can not see the configuration in the dropdown menu in the + of Edit Configurations.

I have placed the class in app/src/androidTest/java.

I have added "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" to testInstrumentationRunner in build.gradle for app.

I have used testInstrumentationRunner.put("class", "....TestSuite").
And I have setRoot to ("src/androidTest")

I have followed this [page](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/#example-buildgradle-file) for setting things up.

Kindly let me know what I am missing. And if you need any more info.

If I right click on the test method and click on Run. It creates an entry in the Android Instrumented Tests in Run/Debug Configurations.